# ionic cordova build android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 30.0.3

Tags: ionic-framework, build.gradle

When I tried to generate apk file ionic cordova build android. I got an error
link below in CMD.

MIN_SDK_VERSION: 21,
SDK_VERSION: 31,
GRADLE_VERSION: 7.3.3,
BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION: 30.0.3,

Ionic Info:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.8 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.14.1\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.10
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.10
@angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.1.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.0, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : not installed globally

System:

NodeJS : v12.14.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.13.4
OS     : Windows 10

> Configure project :app
> Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@2ca1ffdf' is not a valid version number

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> D:\App\app\src\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

BUILD FAILED in 15s
16 actionable tasks: 16 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\App\app\src\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\App\cloudedu-app\src\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I have to update my app on google play store and I'm targeting android Version - 12. I got Stuck last two days. Help me to fix this problem.